# postgres, add row when a value is missing

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, rows, fill

Forgive what may be a silly question, but I'm not much of a database guru.

I have a table with three columns. Here's a sample:

```
stationtest | id_date | val_no3
------------+-------------+---------
27          |  1      |     
27          |  2      |  7        
27          |  25     | 
27          |  50     |  8  
27          |  75     |  9 
27          | 100     | 10
30          |  1      |     
30          |  14     |  7        
30          |  25     | 
30          |  65     |  8  
30          |  75     |  9 
30          | 100     | 10
```

I would like to have a new table that have **one row for each value id_date missing and it combines stationtest number**,
like this one :

```
stationtest | id_date | val_no3
------------+-------------+---------
27          |  1      |     
27          |  2      |  7   
27          |  3      |   
27          |  4      |  
27          |  5      |  
27          |  6      | 
27          | (...)   |       
27          |  25     |
27          |  26     | 
27          |  27     | 
27          | (...)   |  
27          |  50     |  8
27          | (...)   |  
27          |  75     |  9
27          | (...)   |
27          | 98      |  
27          | 99      | 
27          | 100     | 10
30          |  1      |     
30          |  2      |  7   
30          |  3      |   
30          |  4      |  
30          |  5      |  
30          |  6      | 
30          | (...)   |       
30          |  25     |
30          |  26     | 
30          |  27     | 
30          | (...)   |  
30          |  50     |  8
30          |  75     |  9
30          | (...)   |
30          | 98      |  
30          | 99      | 
30          | 100     | 10
```

I have this query but i don't know how to make it work for each stationtest :

```
insert into tabletest (id_date)
select i
from generate_series(1, (select max(id_date) from tabletest)) i
  left join tabletest on tabletest.id_date = i
where tabletest.id_date is null;
```

It is possible ? **Thank you for help.**

Comment: A [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
 st_test integer;
 i integer;
BEGIN
  FOR st_test in (SELECT distinct stationtest FROM tabletest) LOOP
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO test(stationtest, id_date) SELECT $1 as stationtest, generate_series as id_date FROM generate_series((SELECT min(id_date) FROM test), (SELECT max(id_date) FROM test))' USING st_test;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

I don't have the data handy, but the general format should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it could be good but it doesn't work because i need also to add a number for each stations when i add a row like in my example.

Comment: ah ok, I've edited it to take that into consideration.

Comment: I tried it but i have an error : 
[ERROR    ] 1.0: syntax error, unexpected character ; do you know how to do ? (i have postgres 9.3.1 btw)

Comment: Yeah good job man ! But just one last thing, do you know how to 
to prevent it duplicates existing lines when i use the query multiple times ?
For example your query create line 3,4,5 for stationtest, and i would like it don't create anymore if i use again the query

Comment: a couple of ways to do that. I would add a unique key to (stationtest,id_date) since that'd be the easiest. Can you mark as answered?

Comment: I'm sorry my answer isn't totally answered cuz your query add too much lines. I need to add row when a value is missing, for example if i have id_date2 = 2;5 i need to only add 3,4 ; but your query add 2,3,4,5 :(
Can you help me a little bit again please :-) ?

Comment: I was saying you should add a unique constraint on the table, like this: `alter table tabletest add constraint test_uniq unique (id_date, stationtest);`

Comment: If i add a constraint i can't use your query because it generate an extra key who already exists .. :(